# OR condition under scope in Yii

Tags: yii

how do i use OR condition under default scope?

This is not returning anything.

```
return array(
    'condition'=>'id1='.$sid OR 'id2='.$sid' ,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improper syntax, Do this -

```
return array(
    'condition'=>'id1='.$sid.' OR id2='.$sid ,
);
```

This should be the right way to arrange condition and params for your CDbCriteria.

```
return array(
    'condition'=>'id1=:sid OR id2=:sid' ,
    'params' => array(':sid' => $sid)
);
```

Comment: Would suggest using the second one, the first could get you hacked in a hurry :-)